# Localhost failing to start after installing mifos

Tags: web

I installed xampp v 3.2.2, jdk 9.0.4. The xampp package has, Mysql 7.2.3. I installed mifos following the installation guide from the mifosforge.jira.com. All the modules in xampp are working fine. I attempted to launch mifos through running tomcat admin in xampp. However on attempting to start mifos, an error occurred. I am using windows 8.1, 64bit. 
Can somebody please assist on how i can resolve this problem. i have attached the log file and screenshot of the event.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8643.png)

Comment: is tomcat running without errors? you cna also check the file you specified to log errors on installing tomcat.

Comment: Yes tomcat is running fine. Actually i am novice to this, where do i find the file and how do i correct the log errors?

Comment: there is this command you can use in ubuntu environment. 
# tail -f /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out

Comment: Finally fixed problem

Comment: thats awesome, its an interesting project, in case its a gig you would need help am available